# Get file descriptor from file pointer without fileno()

Tags: c

Is it possible to get the file descriptor from a file pointer without using `fileno(FILE* file)`?

Especially, is it possible using only functions from C standard library?
(The reason of my question actually is from the fact that `fileno()` is a POSIX standard function
but not standard C.)

Comment: on linux you can look into /proc/{your process pid}/fd and find the file you've opened and take the corresponding fd

Comment: I think you should post a complete reproducible example for the method you know even if it's trivial and then ask about how you would like to modify it.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid using the reliable and portable method of getting the information?  (It's at least portable to other POSIX systems.)  You can poke around `<stdio.h>` and see if you can identify where the information is stored in the structure underlying a `FILE *`, but that's pointlessly hard work and not reliable (it could be a fully opaque type, though it usually isn't) or portable.

Comment: What's your need to know which is the fileno of a file?

Comment: File descriptors are not part of standard C.  There is no obligation from the C standard for a system to implement the standard I/O library atop file descriptors.  Consequently, there's no way to get the file descriptor from a file stream using standard C; the concept of file descriptor is not a part of the C standard.  That's why `fileno()` is not a standard C function.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler. If fileno is not a standard function what's the value the function `open` returns. Is it fileno? It's fileno if we use Unix?

Comment: The `open()` function is not a part of standard C either; none of the functions using file descriptors are part of standard C.  They are typically part of POSIX, though most systems provide extension functions that are not defined by POSIX but that do use file descriptors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

File descriptors are not part of standard C.  There is no obligation from the C standard for a system to implement the standard I/O library using file descriptors.  Consequently, there's no way to get the file descriptor from a file stream using standard C; the concept of file descriptor is just not a part of the C standard.  That's why `fileno()` is not a standard C function.

The C11 standard [§7.21 Input/output `<stdio.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21) does not specify any functions using file descriptors.

> If `fileno()` is not a standard function, what's the value that the function `open()` returns?

The `open()` function is not a part of standard C either; none of the functions using file descriptors are part of standard C. The [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) does provide functions using file descriptors — lots of them, including [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) and [`fileno()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fileno.html). Most systems provide extension functions that are not defined by POSIX but that do use file descriptors.

Comment: so I guess you answer is "no"?

Comment: No, @OznOg — the answer is indeed No.  ;D